# Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined -JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display different images for background on each click.I have included set of images in array and trying access them using JavaScript. But the code is showing error as

> Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

I have tried many ways to set url. Nothing is working.

`````
<body>
    <div class="arrow right" onclick="channelForward();"></div>
    <div id="tv"></div>
<script>
    function channelForward(){
    var ch=["F:/html/images/1.jpg",
            "F:/html/images/2.jpg",
            "F:/html/images/3.jpg",
            "F:/html/images/4.jpg"
        ];

    var count=0;
    if(count<ch.length)
    {
    document.getElementById("tv").style.backgroundImage=url("ch[count]");
    count++;
        }
     ````
</script>
</body>
`````

I expect url("ch[1]") to display image "2.jpg"  and so on. I'm new to coding,
So please suggest if anything else is wrong in code.

Comment: As it is now, your JS is trying to call a function `url` which doesn't exist. You have to place it inside quotes, like `backgroundImage = 'url("' + ch[count] + '")'`

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the quotes from the variable -

```
document.getElementById("tv").style.backgroundImage="url(" + ch[count] + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your variables:

```
document.getElementById("tv").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + ch[count] + ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add you background images using ES6 template literals like that :

```js
document.getElementById("tv").style.backgroundImage = `url(${ch[count]})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

Number 1: You haven't closed the brace for your function definition. Your last closing brace (`}`) is for the body of an if statement.

Number 2: You have 4 ` at the end of your script block. Just delete those.

Number 3: (as elveti points out) you assign the background incorrectly. The easiest way from the code you have is probably

```
document.getElementById("tv").style.backgroundImage=`url(${ch[count]})`;
```

Number 4: count is set to 0 every time you call the function, so the background image will not change. There are many possible fixes. The easiest is to declare `count` outside the function, giving it "global" scope.

Answer (score -1):

I think this problem may be caused by the absolute path,try to use relative path

```
var ch=["/html/images/1.jpg",
            "/html/images/2.jpg",
            "/html/images/3.jpg",
            "/html/images/4.jpg"
        ];
```

Open chrome,F12,Elements,choose  ,you can find it is whether to load img or not